# How to Build an Android App from a Dynamic Sveltekit Application via Capacitor

Tags: javascript, mobile, svelte, sveltekit, capacitor

I have built a website with Sveltekit that uses form actions in server.page.js files. I want to create an Android application for my website. I decided to use [Capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com) to achieve this task.

However, after I followed the instructions on [the capacitor site for svelte apps](https://capacitorjs.com/solution/svelte) `npx cap add android` command gave the following error:
`[error] The web assets directory (.\build) must contain an index.html file. It will be the entry point for the web portion of the Capacitor app.`

I use [@sveltejs/adapter-node](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-node) to build my app. After some research, I decided to use [@sveltejs/adapter-static](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static) to create a build folder with an `index.html` file. After building my Sveltekit app with static adapter I could build the android app but after opening it, it only displays 500 Internal Error.

[Here is the screenshot from the app built with capacitor and static adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSQk5.jpg)

To sum up, how can I create an Android app with Sveltekit and Capacitor?

Comment: Kindly see this blog post of how to get Sveltekit to work with CapacitorJS. https://ionic.io/blog/cross-platform-sveltekit-capacitor-application-yes-its-possible . Just a head's up; using `adapter-static` will require you to have extra configurations, for example;  for dynamic links and the click back event. Feel free to ask any questions you may have..... I'm hoping to release a tutorial soon, seems like Sveltekit & CapacitorJS has demand

Comment: Hi @NatumanyaGuy : did you ever get to create a Sveltekit & CapacitorJS tutorial?